# Wordpress post title fragment from permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have a links to my post like this: *http://localhost/blog/2017/03/title-of-post*

How can I extract only this fragment: **title-of-post**

I serach a little and I found only extract all without domain, bu I want only my post name. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called slug. There are many way to get the post slug, but the easiest way is:

```
<?php echo basename(get_permalink()); ?>
```

Another way is:

```
<?php 
  global $post;
  $post_slug=$post->post_name;
?>
```

Comment: Looks great, but how I can use it in hyperlink? When I try to use it like these

<a href="<?php basename(get_permalink()); ?>.PDF"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>Download PDF</a></li>

I have a full link for post (not post-name.PDF), but when I try to only echo that post name (after "Download PDF") it works good. Why?

Comment: When you try to use it as a link, you need to include the directory, you only specific the file name (which is the slug) in your href.